# Управление памятью в C, быстрая аллокация и создание своего GC.

Tags: c, сборщик-мусора, память

Я много раз встречал утверждение, что стандартный `malloc` работает медленно, и что не годится для постоянного использования.

Сейчас пытаюсь написать небольшой скриптовый язык на Си, где будет автоматическое управление памятью (GC).

Как пишутся GC? Какую литературу посоветуете?

Ещё интересно, как организовать быструю работу с памятью.

Comment: Использовать Python и расширять, где требуется, своими модулями - вот Вам и GC :)

Comment: В Питоне крайне трудно создать песочницу. Кроме того, я хочу научиться сам, разобратсья в устройстве работы GC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начните с общих сведений. Прочтите об устройстве GC в больших виртуальных машинах, таких как Java и .NET, где GC реализованы весьма хорошо и даже можно выбирать раные реализации.

Вот, для начала можно прочесть на русском [Garbage Collection наглядно](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/java/112676/)

Вот на RSDN про [GC в .NET](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/GC.xml).

Для начала этих сведений будет достаточно, чтобы начать.

Да, и последнее: malloc работает быстро. Если он не работает быстро, то это значит, что вы делаете что-то не то или не так.

Answer (score 1):

Серия статей на русском по сборке мусора в Java от IBM:

- [Краткая история развития технологии утилизации памяти](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp10283/)
- [Сборка мусора и производительность](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp01274/index.html)
- [Сборка мусора в HotSpot JVM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-jtp11253/)

И еще по ссылкам в конце статей много интересного.

PS Сам по себе С malloc работает быстро: это основной функционал языка, он отточен до предела. Возможно, он работает медленнее, чем что-то, но тогда нужно уточнять, с чем идет сравнение.